# How to make text from EditText in AlertDialog available in MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

In my project there is a MainActivity class with victory() method in it :

```
public void victory() {
        name = "";
        AlertDialog dialog = DialogScreen.getDialog(this, DialogScreen.IDD_MAPHIGHSCORE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
        name = DialogScreen.nickname;
        Log.i("NICKNAME :", " " + name);
    }
```

where I call getDialog(Activity activity, int ID) method from DialogScreen class :

```
public class DialogScreen {

static String nickname = "DEF";
public static final int IDD_MAPHIGHSCORE = 1;
public static final int IDD_WORLDHIGHSCORE = 2;

public static AlertDialog getDialog(Activity activity, int ID) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(activity);
    int maxLength = 15;
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    switch(ID) {
        case IDD_MAPHIGHSCORE: {
            builder.setTitle(R.string.newHighScore);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.enterNickName);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setView(editText).create();
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();
                    nickname  = text;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

But in Log.i I can see just "NICKNAME : ". I also tried getters in DialogScreen class and setters in MainActivity class. But this doesn't help.

So the first question is how to make text from EditText available in MainActivity class?

And the second one is how can I know (from MainActivity class) if the button "OK" from dialog has benn pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is a timing problem
Log.i is done before you click the positive button of your dialog.
Add a [DismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)) to your dialog within the MainActivity and move Log.i into that listener.